# input array for ViewModel

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel and one of its elements is a list of integers

```
public class Recurso
{
    [...]

    [Display(Name = "Clientes")]
    public List<int> Clientes { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get this values from an array of hidden inputs in the form that is posted to this action

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdicionarRecurso(Recurso model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewData["sucesso"] = Recursos.NovoRecurso(model);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And in my form, along with fields that correspond to the other parts of my Model, I've got something that goes like

```
[..]
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="15"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="17"/>
[...]
```

I know this is being posted as it should (or at least I thik so) because if Log the form I get this `...&Clientes%5B%5D=1&Clientes%5B%5D=15&Clientes%5B%5D=17`

However when debuging `Clientes` in the Model are still `NULL`

How am I suposed to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
as requested here is the part of my view that generates the form, the hidden array fields are created dynamicaly so i'll had that javascript par too:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "recursoform", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                        {
                            <div class="form-errors">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                                <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo)</div>
                                <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao)</div>
                                <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Ficheiro)</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                <label for="IDTipoRecurso" class="span3">Tipo de Recurso</label>
                                <select class="span5" id="IDTipoRecurso">
                                    @foreach (var tipoRecurso in (List<SMOnline.Models.TiposRecursos>)ViewBag.tiposRecursos)
                                    {
                                        <option value="@tipoRecurso.IDTipoRecurso">@tipoRecurso.Descricao</option>
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo, new { @class = "span3" })
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Titulo, new { @class = "span12", placeholder = "Titulo" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "span3" })
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "span12", placeholder = "Descrição" })
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ficheiro, new { @class = "span3" })
                                <a href="javascrip:;" class="btn btn-large btn-alert span3" style="margin-left: 0;" onclick="getFile()">
                                    Carregar Ficheiro!
                                    <i class="icon-upload icon-large"></i>
                                </a>
                                <label style="padding: 10px 0 0 0;">&nbsp;<i class="icon-ok icon-large" id="fileselected" style="font-size: 30px; color: #090; display: none;"></i></label>
                                <div style='height: 0px;width:0px; overflow:hidden;'>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Ficheiro, null, new { type = "file", @class = "upfile" })</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

                            <div class="input-prepend">
                                <label for="Associacao" class="span3">Disponível para</label>
                                <select class="span5" id="Associacao">
                                    <option value="1">Todos os clientes</option>
                                    <option value="2">Tipos de clientes especificos</option>
                                    <option value="3">Clientes especificos</option>
                                </select>

                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="span3"></div>
                            <div id="clientesEspecificos" class="clientes">
                                <div class="span5" style="margin-left: 0;">
                                    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Filtrar" id="box" class="span5" style="margin-left: 0;" />
                                    <ul class="navList span5" style="margin-left: 0;">
                                    @foreach (var cliente in (List<SMOnline.Models.Entidades>)ViewBag.clientes)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="cliente-@cliente.IDEntidade-@cliente.UserName" class="addCliente" title="adicionar cliente à listagem">@Html.Raw(cliente.UserName)</a></li>
                                        <!--<input type="checkbox" name="Clientes[]" id="cliente-@cliente.IDEntidade" value="@cliente.IDEntidade" class="pull-left" />
                                        <label for="cliente-@cliente.IDEntidade">&nbsp;@Html.Raw(cliente.UserName)</label>-->
                                    }
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="span5">
                                    <div><strong>Clientes Selecionados</strong></div>
                                    <div id="clientesSelect">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tiposClientes" class="clientes span5">
                                @foreach (var tipo in (List<SMOnline.Models.TiposClientes>)ViewBag.tiposClientes)
                                {
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="TiposClientes[]" id="tipoCliente-@tipo.IDTipoCliente" value="@tipo.IDTipoCliente" class="pull-left" />
                                    <label for="cliente-@tipo.IDTipoCliente">&nbsp;@Html.Raw(tipo.Descricao)</label>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Admin")" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
                                    Cancelar
                                </a>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                                    Gravar
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        }
```

javascript:

```
$('.addCliente').click(function () {
            var splitId = this.id.split("-");

            $(this).fadeOut('slow');

            var clienteAdicionado = '<div class="removeCliente" id="removeCliente-' + splitId[1] + '-' + splitId[2] + '">' + splitId[2] + '</div>';
            clienteAdicionado += '<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[1]" value="' + splitId[1] + '"/>';

            $('#clientesSelect').append(clienteAdicionado);

            removeCliente();
        });

function removeCliente() {
        $('.removeCliente').click(function () {
            var splitId = this.id.split("-");

            $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });

            $('#cliente-' + splitId[1] + '-' + splitId[2]).fadeIn();
        });
    }
```

and the initial action:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult AdicionarRecurso()
    {
        Recurso model = new Recurso();

        string email = this.GetEmailFromCookie();
        string key = Admin.GetUserKey(email);

        ViewData["clientes"] = Admin.GetAllClientes(email);
        ViewData["tiposClientes"] = Admin.GetTiposClientes(email);
        ViewData["tiposRecursos"] = Recursos.GetTiposRecursos(key);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Ehsan Sajjad I needed to define `model.Clientes = new List<int>();` on the initial action before sending the model to the view.

As for the form in the view, it turns out that if I don't add brackets to `name="Clientes[]"` nor `name="Clientes[1]"` and instead just name all of them with `name="Clientes"`

as in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes" value="15"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes" value="17"/>
```

The default model binder sees all these name/value pairs with the same name and converts that to a collection with the key ints, which is then matched up with the ints parameter to the action method.

here's the [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) that guided me in the right direction.

Comment: its fine, but in my case passing indexes worked for me

Answer (score 1):

the view output that you have shown is wrong:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="15"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[]" value="17"/>
```

it should be this way:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[0]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[1]" value="15"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Clientes[2]" value="17"/>
```

This is the reason that the list is null in model on action post

and in your initial action, do like this:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult AdicionarRecurso()
    {
        Recurso model = new Recurso();

        model.Clientes  = new List<int>();

        string email = this.GetEmailFromCookie();
        string key = Admin.GetUserKey(email);

        ViewData["clientes"] = Admin.GetAllClientes(email);
        ViewData["tiposClientes"] = Admin.GetTiposClientes(email);
        ViewData["tiposRecursos"] = Recursos.GetTiposRecursos(key);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: it still does the same thing

Comment: can you post the action in which you are populating model and passing to view

Comment: and also post your complete view

Comment: been away for the weekend, i've edited my question with more code

Comment: +1 for defining `model.Clientes = new List<int>();` in the action but the form part doesn't work, found out the solution however.

Comment: how you coped with out, do post the solution

Comment: just answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

First I think you are not passing the model object on your Action, you are passing his field the your model will be null. I suppose maybe retreiving your int by `Request` in the action and then after correct validationn you can create your model with this field (from request) and pass it to the view.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["somekey"]
```